# Inequality Exercise in Apostol's Calculus I

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let p and n denote positive integers. Show that:

$$n^{p} \lt \frac{(n+1)^{p+1} - n^{p+1}}{p+1} < (n+1)^{p}$$

**Attempt at Solution**

Using the identity $b^{p+1}-a^{p+1} = (b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{p}b^{p-k}a^{k}$, let $b = n+1$ and $a = n$. Then:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{p+1} - n^{p+1}}{p+1} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{p}(n+1)^{p-k}n^{k}}{p+1} = \frac{(n+1)^{p} + (n+1)^{p-1}n + .... + (n+1)n^{p-1} + n^{p}}{p+1}$$

I'm not sure where to proceed from here. Am I supposed to use a geometric series in here somewhere?

EDIT: I may have figured it out if someone can confirm that $(n+1)^{p-k}n^{k} > n^{p}$,  $1 \le k \le p$, $\forall n$

Assuming the above is true, we have:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{p} + (n+1)^{p-1}n + .... + (n+1)n^{p-1} + n^{p}}{p+1} \gt \frac{n^{p} + n^{p} + .... + n^{p}  + n^{p}}{p+1} = \frac{(p+1)n^{p}}{(p+1)} = n^{p}$$

Similarly:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{p} + (n+1)^{p-1}n + .... + (n+1)n^{p-1} + n^{p}}{p+1} \lt \frac{(n+1)^{p} + (n+1)^{p}  + .... + (n+1)^{p} + (n+1)^{p}}{p+1} = \frac{(p+1)(n+1)^{p}}{(p+1)} = (n+1)^{p}$$

Comment: For the left hand side, just multiply with $p+1$ and expand the $(n+1)^{p+1}$ using the Binomial theorem.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my question. It's supposed to be $(n+1)^{p}$.

Comment: I think the RHS can be done by expanding the powers on both sides, but I can't do it myself right now and check it.

Comment: What you write in your edit is right. It must be obvious to you that, for every positive integer $k$, $x^k < (x+1)^k$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Yikes, it never registered to me that $(n+1)^{p-k}n^{k} > n^{p}$ is equivalent to $(n+1)^{p-k} > n^{p-k}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The middle term, $\dfrac{(n+1)^{p+1} - n^{p+1}}{p+1}$, equals $\int_n^{n+1} x^p dx$. On the interval $(n,n+1)$, which has length $1$, $n^p<x^p<(n+1)^p$, from which the inequality follows immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value theorem. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

We can use Bernoulli's to strengthen this to $n,p$ positive real numbers. I will show with the LHS.

$(p+1)n^p < (n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}$

$n^p(p+n+p) < (n+1)^{p+1}$

$( p/n+1/n+1) < (1+1/n)^{p+1}$ which just follows from Bernoulli's Inequality. Similar for the RHS. Just write the solution forwards.